# cached aerator with no teeth to grip

Tags: plumbing

Does anyone know the best way to remove a cache aerator from the bathroom faucet that does not have the teeth to grip a key with? I am unable to insert a flathead screwdriver to wedge in as well.

Comment: I'm not sure what a "cache aerator" is, but... A) a picture of the problem will go a long way toward helping us help you, and B) often times they unscrew and you can use a gripper pad (like the one you might use in the kitchen to open a jar of spaghetti sauce) to unscrew it. Of course, it helps if the faucet is nice and dry.

Comment: The 'key' that came with the faucet. Apparently there's at least four different sizes : M16.5-TT, M18.5-TJ, M21.5-JR, M24-STD https://www.amazon.com/JQK-M16-5-TT-M18-5-TJ-M21-5-JR-aerators/dp/B07RKP8N2S

Comment: The teeth may not be visible which is why these are shaped like a socket. If none of those fit, I'd question if it's just a standard aerator and being stubborn (the standard kind that the housing unscrews usually don't have 'flats' on them).